# Excel Formula returning the smallest value, taking into account empty cells

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I have 4 dates across a table, I want to return the smallest date so have used the below, however if that cell is blank I want the cell displaying the date to be blank? This is what I've tried:

```
=SMALL(D2:K2,1,D2,"")
```

It does not work.

Comment: Care to show some sample data and expected return? For now, you have used more parameters than allowed > `SMALL(Matrix, nth smallest)`. Reason I'm asking is that `D2:K2` holds more cells than possibly 4 dates.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly.

If you wish to display the lowest date in the range or - if any of the cells are blank - a blank cell, you might use this formula.
It checks if the number of non-blank cells is 0 and results either in the minimum date or a blank.

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK(D2:K2)=0,SMALL(D2:K2,1),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an IF:

```
=IF(D2="","",SMALL(D2:K2,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the array formula (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to run it), that is needed:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(TRUE(),ISBLANK(A1:A4),0)),SMALL(A1:A4,1),"")
```

The idea is the following:

- get the first cell in the range, which is not filled out with the array formula`=MATCH(TRUE(),ISBLANK(A1:A4),0)`. It will either return a the position of the empty cell or `N/A` error, if there is no such cell.
- put `=IF(ISERROR)` to check whether there is an empty position in the range, returning an error.
- unite the formula with `=SMALL(A1:A4,1)`, if there is no empty cell.

Formulas are in German, but I hope it is understandable:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

=IF(ISBLANK(D2),"",MIN(D2:K2))

Answer (score 0):

You can use the union of two formulas:

The `count.if()` and the `small()`, like I did on this case:

`=IF(COUNT.IF(Q31:Q38;"")>0;"";SMALL(Q31:Q38))`, where `Q31:Q38` is my interval.

On `count.if` we count the number of blank cells (equals to "");

On `ìf`, we verify if our counter is > 0. If it is, our cell receives the "" value. If it isn't, it receives the smaller data value.